# Rotating chapter number in label

Tags: margins, chapters, book-design, thumb-index

I am using blocks on the side of the page to show the chapter number. I am using the example described on this forum ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/show-current-chapter-number-on-each-page-margin/119889)). However, I would like to turn the chapter numbers by 90 degrees. I tried the angle option at several places, but nothing worked. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,numbers=endperiod,titlepage,headinclude,
                footinclude=false,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
                BCOR=5mm,b5paper,fontsize=11pt, american,
                ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{totcount}


%makes blocks with chapter number on the side of the page
\newif\ifMaterial
\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\regtotcounter{chapter}
\setlength\LabelSize{\dimexpr\textheight/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}
\ifdim\LabelSize>2.5cm\relax
  \global\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}
\fi
}
\newcommand\AddLabels{%
\Materialtrue%
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifMaterial%
\ifodd\value{page} %
 \backgroundsetup{
  angle=90,
  position={current page.east|-current page text area.north  east},
  vshift= 10pt,
  hshift=-\thechapter*\LabelSize,
  contents={%
  \tikz\node[fill=gray!50,anchor=west,text width=\LabelSize,
    align=center,text height=15pt,text depth=10pt,font=\large\sffamily] {\thechapter};
  }%
 }
 \else
 \backgroundsetup{
  angle=90,
  position={current page.west|-current page text area.north west},
  vshift=-10pt,
  hshift=-\thechapter*\LabelSize,
  contents={%
  \tikz\node[fill=gray!50,anchor=west,text width=\LabelSize,
    align=center,text height=15pt,text depth=10pt,font=\large\sffamily] {\thechapter};
  }%
 }
 \fi
 \BgMaterial%
\else\relax\fi}%
}
\newcommand\RemoveLabels{\Materialfalse}

\begin{document}

\include{Chapters/Introduction}
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to compile your Minimal Working Example. But I took it from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/show-current-chapter-number-on-each-page-margin/119889).

You were right, to rotate the chapter number, you have to play with the `angle` option. But you also have to change its position (with the two options `vshift` and `hshift`).

```
\documentclass[openany,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1,color=black]{background}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\usepackage{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newif\ifMaterial

\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\regtotcounter{chapter}
\setlength\LabelSize{\dimexpr\textheight/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}
\ifdim\LabelSize>2.5cm\relax
  \global\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}
\fi
}

\newcommand\AddLabels{%
\Materialtrue%
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifMaterial%
\ifodd\value{page} %
 \backgroundsetup{
  angle=-90,
  position={current page.east|-current page text area.north east},
  vshift=-15pt,
  hshift=\thechapter*\LabelSize,
  contents={%
  \tikz\node[fill=gray!30,anchor=west,text width=\LabelSize,
    align=center,text height=15pt,text depth=10pt,font=\large\sffamily] {\thechapter};
  }%
 }
 \else
 \backgroundsetup{
  angle=-90,
  position={current page.west|-current page text area.north west},
  vshift=15pt,
  hshift=\thechapter*\LabelSize,
  contents={%
  \tikz\node[fill=gray!30,anchor=west,text width=\LabelSize,
    align=center,text height=15pt,text depth=10pt,font=\large\sffamily] {\thechapter};
  }%
 }
 \fi
 \BgMaterial%
\else\relax\fi}%
}

\newcommand\RemoveLabels{\Materialfalse}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\AddLabels
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Chapter Three}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Chapter Four}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Test Chapter Five}
\RemoveLabels
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not really understand how the chapter numbers should be rotated. But here is a suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage` to define a new pair of layer page styles.

```
\documentclass[
    twoside,open=right,
    numbers=endperiod,
    titlepage,
    headinclude,
    abstract=off,
    BCOR=5mm,
    a6paper,
    american,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}

\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}
\newcommand\LabelWidth{25pt}
\newcommand\Angle{90}% change the angle here

\usepackage{totcount}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \regtotcounter{chapter}
    \setlength\LabelSize{\dimexpr\textheight/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}
    \ifdim\LabelSize>2.5cm\relax
        \global\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}
    \fi
}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    oddpage,
    textarea,
    width=\LabelWidth,
    height=\LabelSize,
    hoffset=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\LabelWidth\relax,
    addvoffset=\dimexpr-\LabelSize+\LabelSize*\value{chapter}\relax,
    mode=picture,
    contents={%
        \putLL{\textcolor{lightgray}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}%
        \putC{\makebox[0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{\Angle}{\raisebox{-.5\height}{%
            \Large\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter
        }}}}%
    }
]{chapnumbox.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    clone=chapnumbox.odd,
    evenpage,
    hoffset=0pt
]{chapnumbox.even}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers
    [onselect={\DeclarePageStyleAlias{plain}{plain.chapnumbox}}]
    {chapnumbox}{chapnumbox.odd,chapnumbox.even}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers
    {plain.chapnumbox}{chapnumbox.odd,chapnumbox.even}

\AddToLayerPageStyleOptions{scrheadings}
    {onselect={\DeclarePageStyleAlias{plain}{plain.scrheadings}}}

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{chapnumbox}{#1}}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}
    {\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.chapnumbox}{#1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\pagestyle{chapnumbox}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\addchap{Test Chapter without Number}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

and with

```
\newcommand\Angle{-90}
```

[image]

or with

```
\newcommand\Angle{0}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, besides the numbers are not placed in the grey boxes. But then I have to use a different pagestyle (as you defined the chamnumbox), but I have more lay-out things in my pagestyle, which will get lost using this one (like chapter title on top of the page).

Comment: The new defined pagestyle `chapnumbox` uses all the layers of pagestyle `scrheadings`. So you can still use `\ohead` etc. to put contents in the header or footer. Or do you load a different package for header and footer? If you add your settings to your MWE, I can show how this can be done by package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: I have all the lay-out setting in one 'master'file in which the chapters are loaded, so no separate package or file. I am now using the fancy pagestyle, with fancyhead and fancyfoot.

Comment: If your are using `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` and pagestyle `fancy` then package `fancyhdr` is used by your code probably. Maybe you can replace this package by `scrlayer-scrpage` and its commands. But if you want to keep `fancyhdr` then you can not use my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

To make your MWE working, you need to add `\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1,color=black]{background}` to your preamble.

In your document, you have to add `\AddLabels` to activate the code.

This is the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,numbers=endperiod,titlepage,headinclude,
                footinclude=false,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
                BCOR=5mm,b5paper,fontsize=11pt, american,
                ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=1,scale=1,color=black]{background}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{totcount}


%makes blocks with chapter number on the side of the page
\newif\ifMaterial
\newlength\LabelSize
\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\regtotcounter{chapter}
\setlength\LabelSize{\dimexpr\textheight/\totvalue{chapter}\relax}
\ifdim\LabelSize>2.5cm\relax
  \global\setlength\LabelSize{2.5cm}
\fi
}
\newcommand\AddLabels{%
\Materialtrue%
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifMaterial%
\ifodd\value{page} %
 \backgroundsetup{
   angle=90,
  position={current page.east|-current page text area.north  east},
  vshift=10pt,
  hshift=-\thechapter*\LabelSize,
  contents={%
  \tikz\node[fill=gray!50,anchor=west,text width=\LabelSize,
    align=center,text height=15pt,text depth=10pt,font=\large\sffamily] {\thechapter};
  }%
 }
 \else
 \backgroundsetup{
  angle=90,
  position={current page.west|-current page text area.north west},
  vshift=-10pt,
  hshift=-\thechapter*\LabelSize,
  contents={%
  \tikz\node[fill=gray!50,anchor=west,text width=\LabelSize,
    align=center,text height=15pt,text depth=10pt,font=\large\sffamily] {\thechapter};
  }%
 }
 \fi
 \BgMaterial%
\else\relax\fi}%
}
\newcommand\RemoveLabels{\Materialfalse}

\begin{document}

\AddLabels
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]
\lipsum[1-3]
\cleardoublepage
\chapte{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Thanks.  I removed the `\include`s by more verbatim code.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add them. Thanks for doing that!