# Show current chapter number on each page margin using memoir

Tags: memoir, chapterthumb

I'm writing a thesis with the memoir class. I'd like to include a marker with the chapter thumbs in the margin of every page at a height that depends on the chapter number. It should look relatively similar to what is proposed here: [Show current chapter number on each page margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119880/show-current-chapter-number-on-each-page-margin).

What is the best way to implement it using the `memoir` class? I tried the `thumbs` package but it does not seem compatible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your code you are using to begin with your `\documentclass{memoir}` and end with `\end{document}`, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled, its fine if it doesn't have the feature you want.