# Temporary removal of `\ChapFrame` used in 'Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin'

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, boxes

I would like to, temporarely, not assign new coloured boxes for some chapters. Is that possible, e.g. using or resetting the `\ChapFrame` command?

Comment: Please provide a MWE: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to the `\ChapFrame` command as given in [`this answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48648) to [Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48641). In that case, the answer is yes, you can conditionally activate/deactivate the frames. A little example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}
\newif\ifFrame
\Frametrue

% background common settings
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={}
}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

% the main command; the mandatory argument sets the color of the vertical box
\newcommand\ChapFrame{%
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifFrame
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
  {\backgroundsetup{contents={%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[
    fill=\BoxColor,
    inner sep=0pt,
    rectangle,
    text width=2cm,
    text height=4cm,
    align=center,
    anchor=north east
  ] 
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
    {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}%
      \parbox[c][1.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
        \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}}%
  }
  {\backgroundsetup{contents={%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[
    fill=\BoxColor,
    inner sep=0pt,
    rectangle,
    text width=2cm,
    text height=4cm,
    align=center,
    anchor=north west
  ] 
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
    {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}%
      \parbox[c][1.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
        \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}}
  }
  \BgMaterial%
  \fi%
}%
  \stepcounter{chapshift}
}

% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}} 

\begin{document}

\chapter[intro]{Introduction}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Discussion}
\Framefalse
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Conclusion}
\Frametrue
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I defined a boolean switch to activate/deactivate the frames; initially the boolean is true, so the frames are drawn. At any place where you want to deactivate the frames, use `\Framefalse` (possible preceded by a `\clearpage`). To activate the frames, simply use `\Frametrue`.

I also changed from the old syntax for the `background` package used in the linked answer to the newer syntax. Of course, the code with the old syntax can still be used.

Comment: It seems that the `background` package and the `draftwatermark` packages somehow conflict; both a watermark from the  `draftwatermark` package AND a 'draft' watermark, apparently arising due to the `background` package. Before making a MWE: is this a known problem? Also, a message 'Content=' is shown in the upper right corner of the compiled page.

Comment: @Stefan If you simply load both packages, you'll get the result described. Why are you loading both packages, anyway?

Comment: Because I, already, had: 
`\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\today\ \currenttime}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.85}
\SetWatermarkScale{2}`
included... But I now see that the `draftwatermark` isn't the problem; this 'contents=' is still appearing in the upper left hand side of my pages – after invoking `\ChapFrame`. It disappears when I remove (all of) your proposed code.

Comment: @Stefan please open a fresh new question with a proper MWE illustrating the problem. (I ask you to do so because, as you see from my images, the bahviour you mention is not present with my answer).