# How do I fix using the \ChapFrame; temporary removal and permanent attachment of the side thumb headings?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chapters, double-sided, blank-page, ifthenelse

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,10pt]{book} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{captdef}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering\textit{This page is left blank.}}
\vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\imagepage}[1]{%
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=10cm]{#1}}
\vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,contents={}]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
\ifcase\thechapshift orange!30 \or green!30 \or yellow!30 \or red!30\or blue!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\or red!30\else yellow!30\fi}

% the main command; the mandatory argument sets the color of the vertical box
\newcommand\ChapFrame{%
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifodd\value{page}
  \backgroundsetup{contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node[
        fill=\BoxColor,
        inner sep=0pt,
        rectangle,
        text width=1.2cm,
        text height=5.8cm,
        align=center,
        anchor=north east
      ] %
      at ($ (current page.north east) + (2mm,-4.7*\thechapshift cm) $) 
      {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}\parbox[c][1cm][t]{5.5cm}{%
          \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\footnotesize \scshape\leftmark}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}  
\else
  \backgroundsetup{contents={%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[
      fill=\BoxColor,
      inner sep=0pt,
      rectangle,
      text width=1.2cm,
      text height=5.8cm,
      align=center,
      anchor=north west
    ] 
    at ($ (current page.north west) + (0mm,-4.7*\thechapshift cm) $) 
    {\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}\parbox[c][.8cm][t]{5.5cm}{%
        \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\footnotesize \scshape\leftmark}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}  
\fi
\BgMaterial}%
\stepcounter{chapshift}%
}

% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-15]              % This page is left blank.
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-15]
\imagepage{example-image-a}      % For some even pages

\chapter*{Index}
\ChapFrame % <--- 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\end{document}
```

When the new chapter coincides with the even numbered page; it writes a "*This page is left blank.*" on this page and assigns the chapter to the next odd-numbered page. I want to add images to some of these pages instead of writing "*This page is left blank.*". I can't delete a `\ChapFrame` information and page number.

[image]

I want to assign a custom `\ChapFrame` macro to pages like Index page. Since the section is starred, `\Chapframe` takes the name of the previous section. Actually, I want the star section to have the name.

Are they possible?

[image]

Related to: 1) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48648/33075

Related to: 2) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167935/33075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,10pt]{book} 
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=5.5cm,marginparsep=1cm,outer=8cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{captdef}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering\textit{This page is left blank.}}
\vspace{\fill}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\blankpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{plain}
\newif\ifFrame
\Frametrue

% background common settings
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={}
}

%auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
 \ifcase\thechapshift 
pink!80   \or 
green!80    \or 
red!80      \or
magenta!30      \or 
lightgray!80          \else 
darkgray!40       \fi}

% the main command; the mandatory argument sets the color of the vertical box
\newcommand\ChapFrame{%
\Add    EverypageHook{%
 \ifFrame
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
{\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[
fill=\BoxColor,
inner sep=0pt,
rectangle,
text width=1.2cm,
text height=7cm,
align=center,
anchor=north east
  ]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (2mm,-1.5*\thechapshift cm) $) 
{\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}%
  \parbox[c][1cm][t]{7.5cm}{%
    \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
 \end{tikzpicture}}}%
}
{\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[
fill=\BoxColor,
inner sep=0pt,
rectangle,
text width=1.2cm,
text height=7cm,
align=center,
anchor=north west
] 
at ($ (current page.north west) + (0mm,-1.5*\thechapshift cm) $) 
{\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}%
  \parbox[c][.8cm][t]{7.5cm}{%
    \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
 }
 \BgMaterial%
  \fi%
}%
\stepcounter{chapshift}
}

% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-15]              % This page is left blank.
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-15]

\newgeometry{left=0cm,right=0cm,top=5cm,bottom=0cm,marginparwidth=0cm,marginparsep=0cm,outer=0cm}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Framefalse

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1,angle=0]{example-image-a}
\end{center}

\newgeometry{left=1.5cm, right=1cm, top=3cm, bottom=1.5cm, marginparwidth=5.5cm, marginparsep=1cm,outer=8cm}

\chapter*{Index}
\Frametrue
\ChapFrame
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\end{document}
```