# Resetting Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin

Tags: formatting, header-footer, thumb-index

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}
\newif\ifFrame
\Frametrue

% background common settings
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=1,
contents={}
}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
\ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

% the main command; the mandatory argument sets the color of the vertical box
\newcommand\ChapFrame{%
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifFrame
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
  {\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[
fill=\BoxColor,
inner sep=0pt,
rectangle,
text width=2cm,
text height=4cm,
align=center,
anchor=north east
] 
at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
{\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}%
  \parbox[c][1.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
    \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
}
 {\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[
fill=\BoxColor,
inner sep=0pt,
rectangle,
text width=2cm,
text height=4cm,
align=center,
anchor=north west
] 
at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $) 
{\rotatebox{90}{\hspace*{.3cm}%
  \parbox[c][1.5cm][t]{3.4cm}{%
    \raggedright\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
}
\BgMaterial%
\fi%
}%
\stepcounter{chapshift}
}

% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}} 

\begin{document}

\part{PART I}

\chapter[intro]{Introduction}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\cleardoublepage

\setcounter{page}{1}
%\setcounter{chapshift}{0} <<<--- ?

\Framefalse
\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{PART II}


\chapter{Discussion}
\Frametrue
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Conclusion}
\Frametrue
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

I want `\ChapFrame` to be reset in **Part II**. Start at the top right of the page so start from position in **Part I**. Or reset line. I'm sure it might be easy for connoisseurs but I couldn't.

Related to : [Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box-at-the-margin/48648#48648)

Related to: [Temporary removal of `\ChapFrame` used in 'Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167898/temporary-removal-of-chapframe-used-in-chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code works exactly as I want.

> \setcounter{chapshift}{-1}