# Place chapter heading in margin

Tags: formatting, header-footer, memoir

I'm using the memoir class.

I would like the \chapter{xxx} command to place the chapter heading in the margin instead of above the text. Like this:

[image: Chapter heading in margin]

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box-at-the-margin) is somewhat similar, but in that question the person wanted the chapter title in the margin of *every* page. My request is simpler (I hope). I want the chapter title in the margin of the first page instead of above the text.

Do I need to use a similar complex mechanism, or is there a simpler way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Will a new chapter always begin at the top of a page?  Another way of asking this is "what document class are you intending to use?"

Comment: Yes, a chapter always starts a new page. (The default for the memoir class, I believe.)

Comment: Will the title always be short? From your example, it does not take much before it runs out of space.

Comment: @daleif, In my case, there will always be room for the title on a single (vertical) line.

Comment: is the width of the text block the same on all pages, or is it narrowed for the first page of a chapter to accommodate the title?

Comment: The width of the text block is the same on all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that might be used as a building block so see it as a proof of concept.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,graphicx}

% picture syntax with std units
\usepackage{picture,calc,xcolor}

\usepackage{eso-pic}


\makeatletter

\makechapterstyle{hmm}{%
  \renewcommand\chapterheadstart{}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \begingroup%
    \AddToShipoutPicture*{%
      \put(\paperwidth-\foremargin+15mm,
      \paperheight-\textheight-\uppermargin
      ){\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[t]{\textheight}{%
            \makebox[\textheight-\topsep][l]{\hfill 
              \chaptitlefont
              \@chapapp~\thechapter\ --
              ##1}
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
    \endgroup%
  }
  \renewcommand\afterchaptertitle{}
}
\chapterstyle{hmm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks very promising, @daleif. I can probably get this to work with my document. (I'll just wait a few hours before I acknowledge this as an answer.)

Comment: I successfully got this to work with my document. Wonderful. Thank you very much.