# Do not show chapter thumb on first chapter page

Tags: parts, chapterthumb

In the MWE below, the code modified by Gonzalo Medina found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262950/modify-chapter-thumb-for-appendix), I would like to have the chapter thumb to not show up just on the first page of the chapter (i.e. the page where the chapter number and name will be displayed):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,contents={}]{background}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}

% background common settings
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgOpacity{1}
\SetBgContents{}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

% the main command; the mandatory argument sets the color of the vertical box
\newcommand\ChapFrame{%
\def\TitleText{\leftmark}%
\AddEverypageHook{%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}
{\backgroundsetup{
  contents={%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}%
}}
{\backgroundsetup{
  contents={%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
}}
\BgMaterial}%
\stepcounter{chapshift}
}

% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}}

%======================================================================================
%   PAGE HEADERS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\headrulecolor{blue!70}% Set header rule colour to 70% red.
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}


\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\mainmatter
\chapter[Intro]{Introduction}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{This is how we do it}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Some Sample Code}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\part{Part Two}
\appendix
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}{}}
\chapter{This is Appendix A}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Appendix B}
\ChapFrame
\lipsum[1-7]


\end{document}
```

Also, how to remove the chapter thumb box that is being formed between the Parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's better *not* to use the `background` package and let `fancyhdr` do all the job:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{plain}

% auxiliary counter
\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

% the list of colors to be used (add more if needed)
\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}


% redefinition of \chaptermark to contain only the title
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~#1}{}}

%======================================================================================
%   PAGE HEADERS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark%  
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\headrulecolor{blue!70}% Set header rule colour to 70% red.
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\mainmatter
\chapter[Intro]{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{This is how we do it}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Some Sample Code}
\lipsum[1-7]

\part{Part Two}
\appendix
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}{}}
\chapter{This is Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Appendix B}
\lipsum[1-7]


\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.  For some reason, I keep getting a watermark "Draft" when I compile your above code using PDFLaTeX.  Can you tell me how to get rid of this?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. My bad, delete `\usepackage{background}` and replace it with `\usepackage{tikz}`.