# Modify Chapter thumb for Appendix revision 2

Tags: header-footer, chapterthumb

Building from the post found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262950/modify-chapter-thumb-for-appendix) developed by Gonzalo Medina,  how can I go about getting the header in the Appendix section to show up like "Appendix A. This is Appendix A",  while still keeping the chapter thumb untouched.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,contents={}]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\bf\sffamily\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bf\sffamily\scshape\chaptername~\thechapter. \leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\bf\sffamily\scshape\leftmark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
%\headrulecolor{blue!70}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\part{One}
\chapter[Intro]{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{This is how we do it}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Some Sample Code}
\lipsum[1-7]

\part{Two}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}{}}
\appendix
\chapter{This is Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Appendix B}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want in chapter thumb and what in the header? Can you state explicitely? I am confused by the word `untouched`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[scale=1,angle=0,opacity=1,contents={}]{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{chapshift}
\addtocounter{chapshift}{-1}

\newcommand\BoxColor{%
  \ifcase\thechapshift blue!30\or red!30\or olive!30\or magenta!30\else yellow!30\fi}

\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\newcommand{\mymark}{}

\makeatletter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north east]
  at ($ (current page.north east) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\bf\sffamily\scshape\mymark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bf\sffamily\scshape\chaptername~\thechapter. \leftmark%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \node[fill=\BoxColor,inner sep=0pt,rectangle,text width=1cm,
    text height=4cm,align=center,anchor=north west]
  at ($ (current page.north west) + (-0cm,-2*\thechapshift cm) $)
  {\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{4cm}{%
    \centering\textcolor{black}{\bf\sffamily\scshape\mymark}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\newcommand{\headrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\headrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
%\headrulecolor{blue!70}
\newcommand{\footrulecolor}[1]{\patchcmd{\footrule}{\hrule}{\color{#1}\hrule}{}{}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}
  {\vskip 40\p@}
  {\vskip 40\p@\stepcounter{chapshift}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\mymark}{\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\part{One}
\chapter[Intro]{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-7]
\section{This is how we do it}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Results}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Some Sample Code}
\lipsum[1-7]

\part{Two}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\mymark}{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries \appendixname~\thechapter}
\appendix
\chapter{This is Appendix A}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{This is Appendix B}
\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]