# Section Title in rotated vertical box at the margin

Tags: sectioning, rotating

I am using the article document class. Can you help me in having the section Title in rotated vertical box at the margin ? I found a way to do the Chapter Title in rotated vertical box at the margin but I need the section.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, show us a minimal compilable example of your document with the rotated chapter headers, so that someone can adapt the code to rotate the section headers.

Comment: here is the code I used > [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48641/chapter-title-in-rotated-vertical-box-at-the-margin)

Comment: any help please ?